# Create Directories from an array in a for loop

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, scripting, redhat

I have an array of customer names that I want to use to make a directory.  Below is the code I'm running:

```
$ echo "$customerArray=( customer1 customer2 customer3 customer4 customer5 )"

for customerName in $( customerArray ); 
do
    mkdir -p /home/$customerName
    mkdir -p /home/$customerName/outbound
    mkdir -p /home/$customerName/outbound_backup
    mkdir -p /home/$customerName/dropoff
done
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This would be a working alternative using
[brace expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion)

```sh
customerArray=(customer1 customer2 customer3 customer4 customer5)
for customerName in ${customerArray[*]}
do
  mkdir -p /home/$customerName/{outbound,outbound_backup,dropoff}
done
```

Comment: Hey Steven thanks for the response.  I am actually more so trying to test whether or not the for loop I specify above is properly reading in the information from the array.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set a variable inside of a string literal and I'm pretty sure that `$( customerArray )` is invalid as well.  Try the following instead:

```
customerArray=(customer1 customer2 customer3 customer4 customer5)
for customerName in ${customerArray[@]}
do
    ...
done
```

You need to reference an array variable as either `${customerArray[@]}` or `${customerArray[*]}`.  The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays) describes this in more depth.